# How to disable "onclick" event processing on a web page with uBlock Origin?

Tags: firefox, website, javascript, adblock, ublock-origin

Normally when a user clicks a middle mouse button on a link on a web page, the link opens in a new tab. When a user clicks right mouse button, a context menu appears. Now there are some annoying sites that reassign this behavior, so when a user clicks a mouse button, they perform whatever they want, open popup windows, redirect wherever they want.

My guess, this is achieved through adding element event handlers like **onclick="DoSomeAnnoyingStuff"**.

**Is it possible to disable "onclick" event processing on a web page with uBlock Origin?**

Comment: (Temporarily) disabling javascript for the page might be a workaround... but what you're looking for seems like a reasonable option for uBlock... maybe NoScript might be a better idea?

Comment: To turn javascript completely on a web page I need to reload it with javascript set "off". In that case the page completely stops working, all the functionality is gone. Not very useful.

Comment: Yeah, that can happen. That's why No Script might work, it's got pages of options for disabling only some features IIRC

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Since there is no certainty if this can be achieved with No Script, I first would like to find out if this is possible to do with uBlock Origin, because I already have it installed, before exploring other options. Are you referring to this add-on: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/

Comment: That looks like the right NoScript add-on, I haven't used it for a while (switched to Chromium) but it used to have several tabs full of different options to turn off & on. It's [FAQ has a section on "clickjacking"](https://noscript.net/faq#qa7_1) that sounds related

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you can set css properties with uBlock Origin, you can disable `pointer-events`:

```
bluray-disc.de#$#body { pointer-events:none !important; }
```

PS: You might want to change the pointer's look as well:

```
bluray-disc.de#$#body{cursor: default !important; pointer-events: none !important; }
```

and/or [reset it for the element's children](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32208556/3890673).

PPS: You'll find my personal cheat sheet with more like the above [here](https://gist.github.com/crusy/27f17226ce7f92b685e5937967de56ce).